# C# Native Memory Leak

Tags: c#, .net, windows, memory, memory-leaks

I suspect my C# server app (running on win server 2012) has a native memory leak, likely from one of the native libraries I'm using. My app reaches ~2.5GB commited memory after running for about 2 weeks. Looking at a dump using WinDbg, I see 1.9GB of native memory (which keeps increasing). Managed memory did not increase beyond a ±600MB-ish threshold.

Running the !heap -s command I see that two segments take up 1.7GB of heap memory combined, however inspecting those segments with !heap -stat -h (basically following the flow from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg) shows me that the amount of busy bytes combined for both is about 30MB, which leaves me with no idea on what could cause the leak.

I have no option of live debugging the app (connecting with a profiler etc) at the moment, since it is running in production and a performance degradation is out of question. Unfortunately, this behavior is also not reproducible in any other environment available to me.

One of my initial guesses was that this is not a leak but rather just lazy reclamation of memory by the OS (since no other process requires this memory). I could verify this by spinning up processes which eat up a lot of memory, but if I'm wrong my app would crash and that is not a good possibility for me :)

Is there any other way I can understand whats going on in the dump? Any other tool perhaps?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: an approach which helped me in the past was to make a list of libraries in use, then rule out one after the other by code review combined with recherche and testing. In my case, it was a particular version of the ODP.NET provider library that leaked a couple of bytes per procedure I failed to dispose. Undetectable in dev, but adds up quickly in production under heavy load.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems out of the question as most libraries I use are closed source and there are about 40 of them involved in a >500K LOC codebase :(

Comment: then this procedure may help: (1) for each library => library used incorrectly ? fix by adding `using` or `Dispose` or "free()" where missing : get rid of library or replace. (2) heisenbug in library => randomly change order of library calls and hope for the best (3) isolate bugs in libraries and reach out to vendors to have fixed or upgrade to new versions. IMO only (1) would eventually create useful answers here if you could include some minimal, complete examples of library calls you think could be problematic.

Comment: DebugDiag can be quite informative when it comes to native leaks in managed processes:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2895198/debug-diagnostics-tool-v2-0-is-now-available

Comment: Thanks! I'll be checking it out.